# SSMS Agent Job Error - "The Specified @name already exists"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-agent

I'm using SSMS v18.6 to generate an SSIS package (dtsx) with a custom query that parses without error.  I'm trying to automate the package to check for currently running executions and to generate results in two job steps with the SQL Server Agent but the job keeps failing with the error...

> The process could not be created for step 2 of job 0x425BB59FA4097D408FE051A723FD4BE6 (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.

When I script out the job and execute in SSMS as a query execution it generates the error...

> The specified @name ('SV_MANHATTAN_RAD') already exists.

The database/server account definitely has access to the package directory and I don't think that there's any type of permissions or internal firewall issues.  I've set up the job step to use 32 bit runtime in the Execution Options.  I doubt the auto generated script is the issue but am adding it in case it's helpful...

```
USE [msdb]
GO


/****** Object:  Job [SV_MANHATTAN_RAD]    Script Date: 05/03/2021 12:15:23 PM ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 05/03/2021 12:15:23 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'SV_MANHATTAN_RAD', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [AG Test]    Script Date: 05/03/2021 12:15:23 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'AG Test', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'---Logic used to check if the current SQL Server is the primary replica. If so, the job will run. If not, the job will not proceed & fail to the error log.

DECLARE @is_prime bit;

Select @is_prime = (select sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica ( ''CLARITY'' ))

IF @is_prime = 0
BEGIN
PRINT ''EXITING GRACEFULLY'';
THROW 51000, ''This is not a primary replica'', 1;
END', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [GenerateFile]    Script Date: 05/03/2021 12:15:23 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'GenerateFile', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/FILE "\"\\stormontvail.org\sv\deptshares\SVCO1 Reporting\FTP\SSIS PACKAGES\SV_Manhattan_Rad.dtsx\"" /CONNECTION DestinationConnectionFlatFile;"\"\\stormontvail.org\sv\deptshares\SVCO1 Reporting\FTP\Manhattan Rad\SVH-ManhattanCT_.txt\"" /CONNECTION SourceConnectionOLEDB;"\"Data Source=epicclaritysql;Initial Catalog=CLARITY;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;\"" /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

Any suggestions as to what's going on here?

### Discourse from the comments

I'm trying to schedule a daily job with two steps. The first step checks to make sure an ETL isn't running and is used in numerous other jobs without any errors. I've tried removing this step and still get the same error. The second step generates a flat file to be picked up daily and submitted off site to a vendor via FTP. I'm using the SSMS export wizard to generate the package with a custom script, which parses without error but, will not run in the agent job. I'm not familiar with these kinds of scripts and am not sure where to place the drop. – KrazyKlause 14 hours ago

The script you provided is roughly doing the following: adding a job SV_MANHATTAN_RAD, adding a job step AG Test (to check if the current SQL Server is the primary replica) and adding a second job step to generate SVH-ManhattanCT_.txt file. Once run, you should have a job with those two steps in the list of jobs. – sbgdata 13 hours ago

I assume you would want to schedule this job to run daily. Now, could you please tell me more about the package you are generating and a custom script within it? The script you provided, if packed in ssis package, will only be attempting to create the same job over and over again, which makes no sense.. – sbgdata 13 hours ago

Yes the job should run daily. I used the export wizard to generate the package to be used in the second job step (GenerateFile). It runs the query that generates results to a txt file and saves it to a directory for further processing/batching. The script I provided is auto generated by SSMS when I right click on the job, "Script Job As.." and then "Create to". I'm beginning to think maybe I can't mix and match step types T-SQL and SSIS in the same job.

Comment: You have a SQL Agent job definition that you run on the primary and the off node. It defines a 2 step sql agent job. Step 1 attempts to discern whether it's the primary. If so, it goes on to the next step. If not, it raises an exception to abort processing. Step 2 is just running a package from a UNC path. Where does the error come in - is it in job creation or job execution? If Creation, on the primary or a secondary?